# if return date is expired make background color red?

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I have a project for library, one of my forms is `borrowed_book` form in this form I have some controls for taking book borrower information also I have two textboxes for date, one `borrowed_date` and the other for `return_date` and in the same form I have a datagridview named `datagridview1` that displays all borrowed book information also it displays the two dates, my question is when the return date is expired I want to make the background for that cell (datagridview cell) red, I use this peace of code but it does not work

```
if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "return_date")
{
    var returnDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["return_date‌"].Value);
    var borrowDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["borrow_date"].Value);
    if (returnDate > borrowDate)
    {
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        // e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you have this code ?

Comment: in my borrowed_book form

Comment: See my answer. You don't specify, but I don't think you have this code as part of the `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format the cell's background within an event handler for the DataGridView.CellFormatting event:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "return_date")
    {
        var returnDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["return_date‌"].Value);
        var borrowDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["borrow_date"].Value);
        if (returnDate > borrowDate)
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you need to make sure that the event handler is assigned either in the Windows Forms Designer or in code.

Cheers

Comment: what do you mean by event handler you mean CellFormatting event or anything else?

Comment: Yes, I mean you need to handle the DataGridView.CellFormatting event, and within the event handler set the background color. This is where it has to be done.

Comment: how i do this please help me? i use your code but it does not work? i copy and paste your code

Comment: As I said, you need to make sure that the event handler is "assigned" to the event on the DataGridView. This can be done from the Windows Forms Designer by first selecting the DataGridView, and the from the Properties window, go to the events pane, select the  CellFormatting event and select my code from the dropdown.

Comment: code for event handler for CellFormatting event, i dno't make event handler before?

Comment: know i understand you i do this but it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "return_date")
{
    var returnDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["return_date‌"].Value);
    var borrowDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["borrow_date"].Value);
    if (returnDate > borrowDate)
    {


    DataGridViewCellStyle CellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = CellStyle;
    }
}
```

Comment: in any event i use your code... is in the same event as my code?

Comment: it does not work ... i have two dates borrow_date = 2014/03/15 and return_date = 2014/03/18, it must make the background color for the 2014/03/18 date red ... but it does not do this?